# Цепочка редиректов в обратном порядке

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

Не как не могу разобраться, хочу спросить у знатоков, можно ли каким-то образом получить цепочку редиректов до моего сайта от пользователя ? 
К примеру пользователь кликнул на рекламу и она через n-редиректов привела на мой сайт, могу я возможностями js/php узнать через какие сайты прошел пользователь перед тем как попал на мой ?

Comment: прям с момента открытия браузера еще цепочку всю может? :) последний реферер есть у вас в запросе

Comment: дело в том что я пишу CPA рекламную сеть, а на днях наткнулся на аналогичную, в которой была такая реализация. Я пишу на пыхе уже не первый год и не представляю как это можно реализовать на ней, вот и интересуюсь возможно ли это вообще или нет :)

Comment: хз, посмотрите где наткнулись, что за заголовки в запросах редиректов. мб кастомные какие-нить добавляются.